# NewtonSoft JSON within strings serialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given a list of JSON strings is it possible to convert the List to JSON without the serializer thinking that the JSON strings are plain old strings. Using NewtonSoft .NET

Using:

```
List<string> list = { "{"foo": "bar"}", "[ 1, 2, 3]", "{"biz": "baz", "fiz": ["a", "b", "c"]}";
String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
```

at the current moment I get something like this from `json`:

```
"[ \n\r "{"foo": "bar"}", \n\r  "[ 1, 2, 3]", ...]"
```

The serializer treats the json strings like any other strings that have special formatting.
I would like something more like this:

```
"[ 
    {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    [
         1,
         2,
         3
    ], 
    {
         "biz": "baz", 
         "fiz": [
                    "a", 
                    "b", 
                    "c"
                ]
    }
]"
```

something like that with proper indentation.

Comment: Definitely unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Is it something about string formatting? How it relates with JSON?

Comment: check JsonSerializer.Formatting

Comment: Better title: How convince Newtonsoft JsonSerializer to produce indented (nice looking) output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to build the JSON yourself using the Json.NET API instead of writing it by hand. For this, you could use JToken to store your original json strings and then wrap the result inside a JArray. You can then use the ToString method to serialize everything back to JSON when you are done.

```
var finalString = new JArray(list.Select(JToken.Parse).ToArray()).ToString();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i ended up using a JRaw wrapper but I wouldn't of thought to do it if hadn't responded.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```